# ansicon -i not working. ansicon is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: rspec, cmd, ansicon

Tired of looking at black and white error RSpec messages on the command prompt. I've decided to follow this post http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows to install ansicon.

That post directed me to the ansicon github https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon page, which i downloaded. I then extracted everything within the .zip folder inside C:\ansicon. Popped up the command prompt, cd to ansicon, typed the command ansicon -i and is returned with the error "ansicon is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I added C:\ansicon to my PATH environmental variable, and it still does not work. There are no x64 or x86 subfodler within the zip I downlaoded from github.

What am I doing wrong? I have windows 8.1 installed

Comment: There should be x64 and x86 subfolder. May be you have downloaded wrong one

Answer (score 5):

Steps to install ansicon:

1. Download the latest version of Ansicon from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads and unzip it
   into a directory
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder where you unzipped it
3. Now, cd into either x86 or x64 (depending on your machine’s processor) and install it globally on
   your machine (For example, D:\Cucumber\ansi160\x64)
4. Type `ansicon.exe –i` OR `ansicon -i` and press Enter
5. Any program that prints ANSI colors will now display properly on your machine