# I can't understand how to install ansicon

Tags: ansicon

https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/tree/v1.89

I read the included readme.txt file but it mentions x64 and x86 and an ansicon.exe executable, which i can't find anywhere. Maybe I don't understand something fundamental about the process which I'm missing.
All the other instructions I found online were old.
I'm using Windows 10

Comment: You can try this solution
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686763/ansicon-i-not-working-ansicon-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686763/ansicon-i-not-working-ansicon-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-com)

Comment: Instruction states to cd into x64 or x86 which i don't know what they mean by that. There are no such files in the directory

Answer (score 0):

I just ran Ansicon for the first time today so I can help. You need to build the code if you get it from Github because that particular project doesn't include the binaries. You can also get it (a zip file including binaries) from the authors' personal web page at:

http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/

If you do get the zip file, you don't install it using setup.exe or similar. Just unzip the files into a directory of your choosing. Then run the appropriate ansicon.exe (32 or 64 bit) from one of the subdirectories that were unzipped.